# Find the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-\left\lfloor\sqrt{n^2+n+1}\right\rfloor\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, radicals, integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-\left\lfloor\sqrt{n^2+n+1}\right\rfloor\right)\;=\;?\quad(n\in I) \\ \text{where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the greatest integer function.}$$

---

This is what I did:

Since $[x] = x - \{x\}$ we get our limit equal to
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}\right\}$$
Moving the limit inside the fractional part function and replacing $n=\frac 1h \; \text {where } h\to0^+$ we get
$$\left\{\lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{\sqrt{h^2+h+1}}h\right\}$$

Applying L'Hospital Rule, we get our limit equal to $\left\{\frac 12\right\}$ which is $0$.

---

The problem:

The answer in the answer key is $\frac12$. So here, the only problem I seem to find in my solution is that $n\in I$ and simply assuming $n = \frac 1h$ doesn't ensure our $n$ to be an integer.

Can anyone provide a way to either correctly assume a new value for $n$ or any alternate way to solve this?

Comment: i think the limit is zero

Comment: You can't just put the limit inside the $\{\cdot\}$ function. $n-1/n$ does not have a limit, but $\{n-1/n\}$ does have a limit.

Comment: But more importantly, $\{\cdot\}$ is not continuous, so $a_n\to a$ does not mean $\{a_n\}\to \{a\}$.

Comment: You also can't use L'Hopital, beucase that limit is of the form $\frac{1}{0}$, and you'd need an indeterminate form to apply L'Hopital.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $\{\cdot\}$ is continuous at $\frac12$ so moving the limit inside is not wrong.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh, yeah my bad. Can't apply L'Hospital there. But I think moving the limit inside is legal

Comment: Nope, it is not logical (legal is for lawyers) @PratyushYadav . Take $a_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$. Then $\lim\{a_n\} = 1$ and $\{\lim a_n\} = 0$. But the other reason you shouldn't do it is that there are lots of cases where $\lim a_n$ does exist (as in this question) but $\lim \{a_n\}$ does exist.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ah, I don't think you got my point. Fractional part is discontinuous at $x=1$. So in your case, yes, I can't shift the limit inside. But in my (albeit wrongly calculated) answer, I thought the inside limit would evaluate to 1/2 (again, wrong calculation) so I moved the limit inside. That would be correct because fractional part is continuous there. The answer comes out to be wrong because of my incorrect calculations. But, had the inside limit been 1/2, it would have at least been logical.

Comment: I get your point, you are just wrong. But it is true that if the limit inside the fractional part is exactly $1/2$, then the limit is 1/2. But you made the switch before showing that the limit was 1/2. You assumed something unknown. @PratyushYadav

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Okay, I concede.

Comment: See also: [Evaluation of $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{x^2+x+1} -\lfloor \sqrt{x^2+x+1 }\rfloor$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1036936) and [Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-\big\lfloor \sqrt{n^2+n+1} \big\rfloor \right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/521230).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For every natural number, we have
$$\lfloor \sqrt{n^2+n+1} \rfloor =n$$
because $n^2\leq n^2+n+1< n^2+2n+1=(n+1)^2$. So we get
$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty} (\sqrt{n^2+n+1}- \lfloor \sqrt{n^2+n+1} \rfloor)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-n)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+n+1-n^2}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}+n}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+n+1}+n}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Wow. Didn't think it would be this easy. Can you give some elaboration on why the floor function becomes equal to n ? It is intuitively obvious but i don't know how to prove it.

Comment: @user230452 didn't he give the elaboration on the next line? In the inequality, since n is positive. So $n^2+n+1$ lies between $n^2$ and $n^2 + 2n + 1$. And since $\lfloor x\rfloor=$ the greatest integer $\leq x$, the answer is n.

Answer (score 6):

The crux of this is that $\sqrt{n^2+n+1}\approx n+\frac{1}{2}$ for large $n$.

Note that $$n^2+n+1=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\implies\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\frac{3}{4}}{n+\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}$$

One can thus quickly see that for large enough $n$, $n<\sqrt{n^2+n+1}<n+1$, so $\left\lfloor\sqrt{n^2+n+1}\right\rfloor=n$ eventually.

Thus we can see that \begin{align}\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-\lfloor \sqrt{n^2+n+1}\rfloor&=\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-n\\ &=\sqrt{n^2+n+1}-\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\\ &=\frac{\frac{3}{4}}{n+\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{n^2+n+1}}+\frac{1}{2}\\ &\to\frac{1}{2}\end{align}

Answer (score 6):

Alternative idea for proving the essential facts: writing
$$\sqrt{n^2+n+1} = n\sqrt{1+1/n+1/n^2}$$
and using the Taylor series of $\sqrt{1+x}$:
$$1+{\frac{x}2}-{\frac{x^2}8}+O(x^3)$$
we have
$$\sqrt{n^2+n+1} = n+\frac12+\frac3{8n}+O(1/n^2)$$
and
$$\lfloor\sqrt{n^2+n+1}\rfloor = n.$$

Comment: Ah, thanks for contributing, but I am in high school and Taylor Series is not in my syllabus, so I have very little idea about it. I'm sure someone else would find it useful